# How does a webservice check whether a user is allowed to see an item?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm creating a backend web service (asp.net core 2.0) for a mobile app (android). The user of the app should only see his items, and I want to do the check in the web service.

In my controller, I have code like this

```
    [HttpGet( "{id}" )]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get( int id )
    {
        var item = _repository.GetItem( id );
        if (!(await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync( User, item, nameof( IsAllowedToSeeRequirement ) )).Succeeded)
            return BadRequest();
        return new ObjectResult( item );
    }
```

and somewhere, there's an `IsAllowedToSeeRequirement` and an `AuthorizationHandler` implementation that does the actual check:

```
public class IsAllowedToSeeAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<IsAllowedToSeeRequirement, Item>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync( AuthorizationHandlerContext context, IsAllowedToSeeRequirement requirement, Item item )
    {
        if (context.User.Identity.Name == item.Owner)
        {
            context.Succeed( requirement );
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

So far, so good, this works, but it's a lot of code and indirection, not to speak of magic strings (though mitigated by `nameof`)...

I could write

```
    [HttpGet( "{id}" )]
    public IActionResult Get( int id )
    {
        var item = _repository.GetItem( id );
        if (item.Owner != User.Identity.Name)
            return BadRequest();
        return new ObjectResult( item );
    }
```

and skip the requirement class, the handler, the registration of the handler and of the requirement.

In each and every tutorial I read about this kind of stuff, there's always this handler-thing. So I suppose there's a good reason for the laborious way, but can anybody explain what that actually might be?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite broad but let me describe an alternative and common used approach:

To gain access to the web api itself one has to [acquire a token](http://bitoftech.net/2015/02/16/implement-oauth-json-web-tokens-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-and-identity-2/) to authenticate themselves. In that token the userid / name is stored [as a claim](http://bitoftech.net/2015/03/31/asp-net-web-api-claims-authorization-with-asp-net-identity-2-1/). When you access the datastore using the repository you can have a authorization table there and join that table using the user credentials from the token.

See [this blogpost](http://bitoftech.net/2015/01/21/asp-net-identity-2-with-asp-net-web-api-2-accounts-management/) for a complete example.

Some more background material [at the docs](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security).